# Define not evaluating POD?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I was going over the C++ FAQ Lite online. I was browsing inlines again since I haven't found a use for them and wanted to know how the stopped the circular dependency as showed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c) answer. I first tried to do the, "Why inlines are better than defines." example with the following code:

```
#define unsafe(i) \
    ( (i) >= 0 ? (i) : -(i) )

inline
int safe(int i)
{
    return i >= 0 ? i : -(i);
}

int f();

int main(void)
{
    int x(5);
    int ans;

    ans = unsafe(x++);
    cout << ans << endl;
    ans = unsafe(++x);
    cout << ans << endl;

    ans = safe(x++);
    cout << ans << endl;
    ans = safe(++x);
    cout << ans << endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Great. Got the typo out of the way. Not that I'm bitter that I don't find such errors or anything.

The output is now `6, 9, 9, 11`.

However, even with pre-incrementation, shouldn't the first value result in 7?

If the macro is being called twice, then doesn't it go like this:

unsafe(x) // pre-incrementation doesn't modify the value when called.

unsafe(++x) // for all intents and purposes, the incrementation happens before the second call, so the ++x. This is for the first `ans = unsafe(x++)` if it's being called twice.

By the time we reach the second `ans = unsafe(++x)`, shouldn't the x have been incremented twice? Once by the double call and once when the first double call was finished?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo here, or in your actual code, but the macro should be `( (i) >= 0 ? (i) : -(i) )`. (`?` instead of `=`)

Comment: Yes, yes it is. This is quite the stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
#define unsafe(i) \
    ( (i) >= 0 = (i) : -(i) )
```

I think you want:

```
#define unsafe(i) \
    ( (i) >= 0 ? (i) : -(i) )
```

In response to your edit:

After the first call to `unsafe(x++)`, `x` is 7, even though the `ans` is 6.  This is because you have the statement:

```
ans = ( (x++) >= 0 ? (x++) : -(x++) )
```

`ans` is assigned to the middle `x++` *after* the left-most `x++` is evaluated.  As a result, `ans == 6` but `x == 7`.  The difference with `unsafe(++x)` is that `ans` is assigned to `++x`, meaning the result is `ans == x == 9`.

Comment: For some reason I had to stare at that for 30 seconds until I noticed the difference. I curse you, ternary `?:` operator!

Comment: Same, but that makes it all the more infuriating when you notice that you just exposed your typo on SO :P Updated question!